# How to understand this bash script debugging framework?

Tags: bash

I try to understand the following script debug framework.

```
#!/bin/bash
_DEBUG="on"
function DEBUG()
{
 [ "$_DEBUG" == "on" ] &&  $@
}

DEBUG echo 'Reading files'
for i in *
do
  grep 'something' $i > /dev/null
  [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "Found in $i file"
done
DEBUG set -x
a=2
b=3
c=$(( $a + $b ))
DEBUG set +x
echo "$a + $b = $c"
```

I could not understand the function DEBUG and its usages.

My question is

(0) What does $@ mean?

(1) how does DEBUG echo 'Reading files' work using $@?

(2) How does

```
DEBUG set -x
a=2
b=3
c=$(( $a + $b ))
DEBUG set +x
```

work using $@?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$@** expands all the parameters passed to a function (or the bash script itself)

For example. If you call `DEBUG echo "test"` the special variable `$@` will expand to `echo "test"`.

The `DEBUG` function just check if `$_DEBUG` variable is set to `"on"`. If so, it executes the command passed as parameter (stored into `$@` variable)

The `set -x` will make the interpreter print each command right before it is executed, so it will aid you in knowing what is happening at any point in time.

`set +x` will restore the normal behaviour

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. They are quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

(0) See [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). `$@` is the list of all the positional parameters.

(1) `DEBUG echo 'Reading files'` calls DEBUG with two parameters, `echo` and `Reading files`. As the result, `echo Reading files` is calles.

(2) `set +x` makes bash print the command and their arguments as they are executed. DEBUG works with `$@` the same way as in (1).